# Module xfrm_user is in use

Tags: 14.04, networking, vpn, ipsec, openswan

I've installed Openswan in Ubuntu 14.04 using

```
sudo apt-get install l2tp-ipsec-vpn
```

Upon configuration for accessing my client VPN network (every time I had to change the password as it is dynamic), I used to restart ipsec and xl2tpd using the following commands

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ipsec restart
sudo /etc/init.d/xl2tpd restart
```

Everything was well and good, until I updated my kernel to **4.4.0-71-generic**.

Now whenever I restart the ipsec, using

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ipsec restart
```

it shows me

```
ipsec_setup: rmmod: ERROR: Module xfrm_user is in use
```

And the connection times out on trying to connect.
I've tried searching over the internet, but yet to get a possible solution for the same.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I know it was a while back, but do you remember if this got fixed by a kernel update or by something you did?